# how to validate form using name or id attribute in angular Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

In form I have controls with name,id and class attribute. I cant add any costom attribute in html input element.
 In this case how can I apply validation.

Can I write directive on element name or id?

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal text-center" role="form" name="DTOstep1" ng-submit="onSubmit(DTOstep1)" novalidate>
<input name="userinput1" id="userinput1" class="" />
<input name="userinput2" id="userinput2" class="" />
<input name="saveDto" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

directive code

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
            .module("autoQuote")
            .directive('userinput1', [userinput1])
            ....
```

Or is there any other way to do form validation. I wan to apply some custom validation to each form field.

Answer (score 1):

The `angular way` requires the `ng-model` attribute to each field, in order to bind it with a model property.

```js
function TestCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.fields = {
    "userinput1" : "Initial Value",
    "userinput2" : ""
  }
  
  $scope.onSubmit = function onFormSubmit($event, form) {
    if(form.$invalid) {
      console.log("invalid", form);
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
    
    console.log('valid', form);
    //send here
  };
}
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .controller("TestCtrl", ["$scope", TestCtrl])
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="test">
  <article ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <form name="DTOstep1" ng-submit="onSubmit($event, DTOstep1)">
      
      <input name="userinput1" ng-model="fields.userinput1" required/>
      <input name="userinput2" ng-model="fields.userinput2" required />
      
      <input name="saveDto" type="submit" ng-disabled="DTOstep1.$pristine || DTOstep1.$invalid" />
</form>
  </article>
</section>
```

---

**by the way**, if you can't edit the view in order to create an angular-form, you need to control the form via dom queries, such as vanilla javascript... using `document.querySelector()` and checking `value` property.

---

## UPDATE

Many basic check could be made using simple procedural approach, if you want apply a minlength to the userinput1 field, on each `onSubmit` you need to check `$scope.fields.userinput1.length > ...`, et cetera...

A more clean and suggested way is to use html5 validation attributes,
angular decorates them and recognize thei rules, so, you can use `min/max/min-length/max-length/required/pattern/disabled` etc.

if you want to provide a reusable way, you should have a look at `FormController.$addControl` or how build a custom directive via attributes that requires `ngModelController` and so on...

Comment: using TestCtrl an ng-model is helpfull. how can I apply validation on input here?

Comment: Can I make rules that I can apply to fields, so that we could reuse rules for multiple filed if required.

Comment: If I make attribute like myInput="userinput1"  and for next myInput="userinput2". then can I apply validation on myInput attribute value.

Comment: <input myInput="userinput1"  name="userinput1" ng-model="fields.userinput1" required/>

Comment: the `myInput` attribute doesn't exist... what do you mean with it? A custom Directive? For doing what?

Comment: I can add something like in element. myInput="userinput1" will it help ?

Comment: I think not, as I said, there aren't html valid attributes like them. If you want to validate an input value you need to do it in the `onSubmit` callback or using a `ng-change` attribute on a single field.

Answer (score 0):

angular automatically adds classed to each ng-model

This should help
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Adding a fiddle as an example

https://jsfiddle.net/x0f6czfk/

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <form ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="name" type="text">
    <input ng-model="email" type="text">
    <input type="button" ng-click="validateForm()" value="Save">
  </form>
</body>

(function(window,document,undefined){
var app = angular.module('app',[]);


  app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope){
    var self = this;
    $scope.validateForm = function(){
    //custom validation
        if($scope.name === 'test'){
        console.log('wrong name');
        return;
      }
     //custom validation
     if($scope.email === 'test@demo.com'){
                console.log('wrong email');
          return;
        }
      else{
      //if no validation error, submit data;
        console.log('valid form');
      }
    }
  });
})(window,document)
```

Comment: Yes, but those classes are same for all controls. How to distinguish each field. Like I want to apply validation form userinput1 only.

Answer (score 0):

Add **required** to those fields on which you want to add validation -

```js
'use strict';
 var app = angular.module("demo", [], function($httpProvider) {

});

app.controller("demoCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.onSubmit = function(){
      alert('form valid');
      }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="demo">
<div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
<form name="form" id="form" class="form-horizontal text-center" role="form" >
<input ng-required="true" ng-model="userinput1" name="userinput1" id="userinput1" class="" /><br>
Check it to make userinput 2 required:  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check" />
<input  ng-required="check" ng-model="userinput2" name="userinput2" id="userinput2" class="" />
<br><input ng-click="onSubmit(DTOstep1)" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" name="saveDto" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Continue" /><br>
</form>
  </div>
</body>
```

you can also use ng-model inside ng-required to toggle the ng-required true and false.

Comment: require is there with all fields. i want to apply some custom validations.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. Can you please explain?

Comment: what kind of custom validation you want?

Comment: something like check value in a set. or validate from server call(Ajax)

Comment: i have added checkbox validation just for demo purpose it can be as complex as you want and for server validation you have to do it in controller onsubmit function